# JavaScript AddEventListener does not work properly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am going to develop a simple bookmark app following a tutorial, using java script as I am a beginner to javascript. I use custom.js file to keep the javascript code separately and link it to the bottom of the code. I use `addEventListener` to form submission and use `console.log` to see the output to check its result. But it doesn't give me any error and does not work `addEventListener` too. As it does not give an error message I am unable to find the issue with my code.IF someone can help me, I highly appreciate your help . Thank You . I have index.html and custom.js files.

```js
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', saveBookmark);

//function saveBookmark
function saveBookmark(e) {
  console.log('Works');

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<main role="main" class="container" id="mainc">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 id="titlehead">App</h1>

    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="myform">
      <!--form field to input name-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="sitename" class="form-control" placeholder="Website Name">
      </div>

      <!--form field to input url-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="siteurl" class="form-control" placeholder="Website URL">
      </div>

      <input type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    <!-- Eof Form -->
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to attach the function to *submit* event and your button type is *button*, the event is not firing. Change that to *submit*:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
```

```js
// Event for form Submission
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', saveBookmark);

//function saveBookmark
function saveBookmark(e) {
  console.log('Works');

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<main role="main" class="container" id="mainc">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 id="titlehead">App</h1>

    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="myform">
      <!--form field to input name-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="sitename" class="form-control" placeholder="Website Name">
      </div>

      <!--form field to input url-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="siteurl" class="form-control" placeholder="Website URL">
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    <!-- Eof Form -->
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mamun, I found it, that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your input type is Button, make type as submit :)

```js
// Event for form Submission
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit',function saveBookmark(e){
console.log('Works');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<main role="main" class="container" id="mainc">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 id="titlehead">App</h1>

    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="myform">
      <!--form field to input name-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="sitename" class="form-control" placeholder="Website Name">
      </div>

      <!--form field to input url-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="siteurl" class="form-control" placeholder="Website URL">
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    <!-- Eof Form -->
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

your input type must be `type=submit` ,

read more here : https://javascript.info/forms-submit

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('myform');
if(ele.addEventListener){
    ele.addEventListener("submit", saveBookmark, false);  
}


//function saveBookmark
function saveBookmark(e) {
  console.log('Works');
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<main role="main" class="container" id="mainc">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 id="titlehead">App</h1>

    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="myform">
      <!--form field to input name-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="sitename" class="form-control" placeholder="Website Name">
      </div>

      <!--form field to input url-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Site URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="siteurl" class="form-control" placeholder="Website URL">
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    <!-- Eof Form -->
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Event for form Submission
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function saveBookmark(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Works');
});
```